# Python hash function as Twisted xmlrpc class issueing same has for every file?

Tags: python, hash, twisted, sha1

I'm new to most of this so forgive me if I'm doing something really dumb.  The following is a simple Twisted xmlrpc server which is supposed to return file info.  It works fine except that the `xmlrpc_hash` function gives the same result for every file.  Example below code.  Any help would be great!

```
from twisted.web import xmlrpc, server
import os

class rfi(xmlrpc.XMLRPC):
    """
    rfi - Remote File Info server
    """

    def xmlrpc_echo(self, x):
        """
        Return all passed args as a test
        """
        return x

    def xmlrpc_location(self):
        """
        Return current directory name
        """
        return os.getcwd()

    def xmlrpc_ls(self, path):
        """
        Run ls on the path
        """
        result = []
        listing = os.listdir(path)
        for l in listing:
            result.append(l)
        return result

    def xmlrpc_stat(self, path):
        """
        Stat the path
        """
        result = str(os.stat(path))
        return result

    def xmlrpc_hash(self, path):
        """
        Hash the path
        """
        from hashlib import sha1
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            f = open(path,'rb')
            h = sha1()
            block_size = 2**20
            f.close()
            return h.hexdigest()
        else:
            return 'Not a file'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    r = rfi()
    reactor.listenTCP(7081, server.Site(r))
    reactor.run()
```

Example output:

```
import xmlrpclib
s = xmlrpclib.Server('http://localhost:7081/')
s.hash('file_1.txt')
'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'
s.hash('file_2.txt')
'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'
```

Comment: Voting to close as too localized because “This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to … a narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.” In future, please try to post only the minimal amount of code required to recreate your problem.

Comment: point taken, but in my defense, I wasn't sure if it was the twisted object or the hash function that was the issue

Comment: Of course — no worries. Just know that it's easier to answer questions with a higher signal-to-noise ratio, they are more likely to help future visitors, and (at least in my experience) I often find the solution to my problem  in the process of narrowing down the code which is at fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're never actually updating the hash object:

```
    from hashlib import sha1
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        f = open(path,'rb')
        h = sha1()
        h.update(f.read()) # You're missing this line
        f.close()
        return h.hexdigest()
    else:
        return 'Not a file'
```